# Получить html код по socket C++ Parses html-code use SOCKET

Tags: html, c++, сокет

Я видел, что это возможно. Но у меня не получается. I see, what this perchance. But for me this difficulry.

```
struct addrinfo addr;
struct addrinfo *urlAddr;
struct sockaddr_in addrList;
char buff[4000];

// addrList = (sockaddr_in *)&((sockaddr_in *)&urlAddr->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
WSADATA wsaData;
int connSock = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (0 != connSock)
{
    cout << "Error 1.";
}

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.ai_family = AF_INET;
addr.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
addr.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

int iResult = getaddrinfo((const char *)&"goatghosts.000a.biz", 0, (struct addrinfo *)&addr, &urlAddr);
if (iResult != 0)
{
    cout << "Error " << iResult << "\n";
}

addrList.sin_family = AF_INET;
addrList.sin_addr.s_addr = ((sockaddr_in *)&urlAddr->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
addrList.sin_port = htons(80);

SOCKET so = socket(
    AF_INET,
    SOCK_STREAM,
    IPPROTO_TCP);

if (connect(so, (const sockaddr *)&addrList, sizeof(addrList)) != 0)
{
    cout << "Error connect " << WSAGetLastError() << "\n";
}

int colbyte = recv(so, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);

cout << colbyte;

return 0;
```

Если вводить ya.ru, то ждем две минуты и выдает ошибку 10060.
А если какой-либо другой адрес, то моментально выдает 10049.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Зачем сокеты? Есть куча более удобных и простых способов для работы с HTTP-серверами.

Comment: 10060 - превышен интервал ожидания. 10049 - нельзя забиндиться (противоположная сторона не открывает сокет)

Comment: А противоположная сторона вообще не будет открывать сокет, если я буду обращаться через connect? Я просто хочу поставить точку раз и навсегда. По мне, использование сокетов было бы куда выгоднее, чем испоьзование HTTPRequest и HTTPResponse. Или есть другие методы стандартных возможностей Visual C++?

Comment: Скажите, я правильно использовал структуру addrinfo и getaddrinfo?

Comment: На первый взгляд Вы тут  перемудрили (детально разбирать сейчас некогда). Пример из [man getaddrinfo](http://ru.manpages.org/getaddrinfo/3) для клиентской программы после замены `SOCK_DGRAM` на `SOCK_STREAM` для адреса mail.ru прекрасно отработал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то, во-первых, правильнее будет поступить так, как Вам уже указали в комментариях - работать с http другими более удобными способами. Все-таки в данном случае, чтобы опуститься на более низкий уровень нужны веские основания. Например, изучить строение велосипеда (но никак не изобретать его снова).

Во-вторых, как также было замечено в комментариях, Вы действительно что-то перемудрили (особенно с адресацией).

В-третьих, даже если разберетесь с ошибками в адресации, то ничего так и не дождетесь. Почему? Да потому что Вы ничего у сервера и не просите.

Если все подытожить, то имеем на выходе примерно следующее:

```
    struct addrinfo *urlAddr, addr;
    char buff[4000];

    //обратите внимание, что здесь указывается также порт.
    //Он в последствие записывается в urlAddr и будет
    //использован при подключении. Указывать отдельно его
    //не придется.
    int iResult = getaddrinfo("goatghosts.000a.biz", "80", &addr, &urlAddr);
    if (iResult != 0) std::cout << "Error " << iResult << "\n";

    int so = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    //Вы уже получили структуру с адресом и портом для
    //подключения. Соответственно в коннекте ее и используете.
    //Нет необходимости еще в каких-то дополнительных
    //преобразованиях и телодвижениях.
    if (connect(so, urlAddr->ai_addr, urlAddr->ai_addrlen) != 0)
    std::cout << "Error connect " << "\n";

    //Если хотите что-то получить от сервера, то сформируйте
    //хоть какой-то минимальный запрос. Когда Вы обращаетесь
    //по указанному адресу в браузере, то он за Вас отсылает
    //его - таковы уж требования протокола. А уж коль Вы
    //опускаетесь на уровень ниже и решили сами реализовывать
    //обмен по протоколу HTTP, то следуйте его "традициям"
    //и требованиям.

    std::string str = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n";
    str+="Host: goatghosts.000a.biz\n\n";

    send(so, (void*)str.c_str(), str.size(),0);
    int colbyte = recv(so, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);

    std::cout << colbyte;
```

Comment: Как обидно мне сейчас это видеть. Потому что я пришел на этот форум, чтобы поделиться своим здоровым кодом, который я перелопатил за день угнетения. Я был очень подавлен, что даже find() не хочет работать со мной и из-за этого такой плохой код вышел. Но к вечеру Я взялся за ум. Во-первых, получил ответ от recv "0 байт получено", для этого прочитал статью из комментариев выше, огромное спасибо человеку оставившему нам это. Ответ 0 дал мне понять, что сокет на другой стороне не открывается.

Comment: Я решил, что используется технология HTTP как класс. Оказалось, встроенного такого не существует. Что дало мне понять, что всё таки я был прав, в том, что начала копаться именно в сокетах. Я не люблю использовать чужой код, люблю писать свой, на С++ это плохо получается. Поэтому, гуглим "устройство http запроса" первая строка выдает нам теорию. И с этой теорией, если мы умеем пользоваться сокетами на уровне байтов, ответ от сервера будет 326 байт. "ya.ru".

Comment: @Вячеслав В принципе, я сам отношусь к тем людям, которые не любят использовать чужой код и любят писать свой. Но, к сожалению, это не тот случай. Сам я использую для работы с http библиотеку [curl](https://curl.haxx.se) - проверена временем, кроссплатформенна, имеется обширный мануал и множество примеров в сети. А работу с сокетами нужно изучать. Их применение очень и очень широко.